# Laravel Restful Api: Session Does Not Gets Submitted

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to build my own API.

Basically, I have made this API Controller method for registering new users with mobile number:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation Data
        $validData = $this->validate($request, [
            'user_input' => 'required|unique:users,usr_name|unique:members,mbr_mobile|regex:/^09\d{9}$/|max:11|min:11',
        ]);
        
        session(['user_phone_number' => $request->input('user_input')]);

        // dd(session('user_phone_number')) properly returns the entered phone number
        
        $sms = new SendSms(request()->all()['user_input'],43,request()->all());
        $sms->send();
        
        return response([
            'data' => 'Verification code has been sent',
            'status' => 200
        ]);
    }
```

And it works fine and properly sends a verification code to user mobile phone number.

And as you can see in the code, I have called a session variable and assigned it to user mobile number:

```
session(['user_phone_number' => $request->input('user_input')]);
```

Now for verifying code, I added this method:

```
public function verifyCode(Request $request)
    {
         dd(session('user_phone_number'));
    }
```

But now the problem is, `dd(session('user_phone_number'))` at **`verfiyCode`** method returns *`null`* somehow!

Therefore I don't have the user phone number for verifying the code.

So if you know how can I send the user phone number properly as session to another method (or any other way), please let me know...

---

### **UPDATE #1:**

Here are my `api` routes:

```
Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\v1')->group(function(){     
    Route::post('register','UserController@register');  
    Route::post('verify-code','UserController@verifyCode');
});
```

### **UPDATE #2:**

Here is my `session.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc", "memcached", or "dynamodb" session drivers you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

Comment: How is the API called?

Comment: @Olivier I just added my api routes, please check it out ...

Comment: What driver are you using for sessions? If Cookies, make sure that your php instance has cookies enabled

Comment: @yetep93258 That doesn't answer the question. Who calls the API? An AJAX request? A desktop application?

Comment: @Olivier I call it on Postman

Comment: @JordanCasey I just added my `session.php` contents

Comment: @yetep93258 first, RESTful Api are stateless and having sessions violates that as they are no longer stateless. second, if your api is not being called by any web app you don't need to use session, you can use sql/redis or anything instead of session to store the mobile number and the otp for verification purpose

Comment: @Haridarshan Can you link me an article or any reference for that please ?

Comment: If you don’t have a reason not to just store it in the user table, then I suggest to just store it there and have a Boolean to mark whether the number is verified or not. You can get the number by calling Auth::user()->phone_number or whatever field you name it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session identifier is transmitted via a cookie. By default, the cookie name is `laravel_session`.

That means that, if you want to use a session in your API, you must transmit that cookie in every
request that accesses the session. If you don't do that, then Laravel will create a new session.

You obviously didn't transmit the cookie in your tests with Postman, hence the empty session.

Remark: a RESTful service is supposed to be stateless, which means no session. Your API does not follow the REST principles.

Comment: So should I do it with API_TOKEN ?

Answer (score 0):

Find your ***app/Http/Kernel.php*** and add ***"sessions"*** value to ***$middlewareGroups*** like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],

        'sessions' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ]
    ];
```

Then add some middleware to your whole block of api.php like this:

```
Route::middleware('sessions')->name('api.')->group(function (){
    Route::post('/usersList', [UserController::class, 'usersList'])->middleware(['hasPermission:ucvSystemUsers'])->name('users.list');
});
```

Forget about y inner middleware *"middleware(['hasPermission:ucvSystemUsers'])"*. I wrote this to manage my user permissions.

**At the end, I'm using this method and there is no problem at all!**

Comment: just put the route under the web middleware

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote this block of code in routes/web.php and it works really fine:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    session()->put('user_phone_number', 'my phone number is here');
});

Route::get('/check', function () {
    dd(session()->has('user_phone_number'), session()->get('user_phone_number'));
});
```

And also your code is fine, there must be another problem. You should check your server session settings

*==========  UPDATE  ==========*

***I forgot to say*** why don't just add these API routes with a session to your web group routes (in routes/web.php) like this:

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        session()->put('user_phone_number', 'my phone number is here');
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/check', function () {
        dd(session()->has('user_phone_number'), session()->get('user_phone_number'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm talking about api man!!!

Comment: I tried what you suggested and results of `dd(session()->has('user_phone_number'), session()->get('user_phone_number'));` is **false** & **null**!

Comment: I think you have problem in your middlewares. Please follow my next anser